# How can I use environment variables in fluentd config?

Tags: ruby, environment-variables, fluentd, td-agent

I have problem with using env at td-agent config, I tried:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /home/td-agent/test.txt
  tag "#{ENV['WEBTEST']}"
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/td-agent-test.pos
  @include /etc/td-agent/web_parse_regex.conf
</source>
```

/etc/sysconfig/td-agent :

```
export WEBTEST="webtest"
```

and when I start td-agent and check td-agent.log, tag is empty

```
2020-06-09 15:40:20 +0900 [info]: using configuration file: <ROOT>
  <source>
    @type tail
    path "/home/td-agent/test.txt"
    tag ""
    pos_file "/var/log/td-agent/td-agent-test.pos"
    .....
```

+I'm using centos

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the `/etc/sysconfig/td-agent` have execute rights

```
chmod a+x /etc/sysconfig/td-agen
```

and to make sure that the init script is executing these files, the below lines need to be in the file `/etc/init.d/td-agent`

```
TD_AGENT_DEFAULT=/etc/sysconfig/td-agent
# Read configuration variable file if it is present
if [ -f "${TD_AGENT_DEFAULT}" ]; then
  . "${TD_AGENT_DEFAULT}"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

could not find a way to set env vars from inside the conf file, but you can set variable values in ruby in the `system` blocks and reuse them in the conf file.

```
<system>
  "#{MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING='mongodb://localhost:27017/test'}"
</system>

<match>
  @type mongo
  connection_string "#{MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING}"
  # database test
  collection fluentd
</match>
```